# How do I force "add to a team" option using teams "deepLink"?

Tags: microsoft-teams

My Teams application supports both "personal tab" and the "teams tab". Is it possible to trigger "add app" dialog in a way that it pre-selects "add to teams" option?

One can trigger this dialog using this [deep link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-an-app) for example:

`https://teams.microsoft.com/l/app/49e6f432-d79c-49e8-94f7-89b94f3672fd`

BUT, this always brings up a tab "add app". If the app is already added this does not make sense (it shows "open") but I would like to show "add to tab" option instead.

Would like to have sort of a parameter for that url maybe?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is not possible. you can submit a feature request on [Microsoft user voice](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).